# $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to prove that $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1)$.

I have by Proposition 3.117 from Rotman´s Advanced Algebra that both are fields and we have that:

$$\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+1)= \lbrace a+ b\alpha / \alpha^3-\alpha^2+1=0 \rbrace$$

And;

$$\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1)= \lbrace a+b \beta / \beta^3-\beta^2+\beta+1  \rbrace$$.

So how can I define a properly isomorphism between both fields? Thanks

Comment: Since there are both 27 elements in each field, you.may as well list the elements out, and claim that two finite fields with the same number of elements are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Think of $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3-x^2+1)$ as the algebra $A=\mathbb F_3[a]$ generated by $a$ satisfying the relation $a^3 - a^2+1=0$. And similarly, think of the second field as $B=\mathbb F_3[b]$ with $b$ satisfying $b^3-b^2+1=-b$. Now, to define a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ it is necessary and sufficient to find an element in $B$ that satisfies the same relation over $\mathbb F_3$ as $a$. With $c:=b+1$, we have $c^3-c^2+1=b^3+1-b^2-2b-1+1=b^3-b^2+1-2b=-b-2b=-3b=0$ (where we have used the relation $b$ satisfies and the fact that we are working in characteristic $3$). Thus, the homomorphism sending $a$ to $c=b+1$ should do the trick. The inverse homomorphism should be obvious.

EDIT: Mike described the inverse of this homomorphism in his answer, his $\delta, \gamma$ correspond to my $a, b$ respectively. Note that $+2=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Both are 27-element fields. As all fields of the same size are isomorphic to each other, that established isomprhism.

As for defining this isomorphism explicitly, note the following: Let $\gamma$ be the root of $x^3-x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$, and let
$\delta$ be a root of  $x^3-x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$. Then $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x^2+1) = \mathbb{F}_3[\gamma]$ and $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1) = \mathbb{F}_3[\delta]$.

A mapping $\phi: \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x^2+1) = \mathbb{F}_3[\gamma] \mapsto \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1) = \mathbb{F}_3[\delta]$ that fixes $\mathbb{F}_3$ is an isomorphism iff the following holds:

> Property 1: For each polynomial $p$ with coeeficients in $\mathbb{F}_3$, the following holds: $p(\gamma)=0$ iff $p(\phi(\gamma))=0$

However, note the following: both $\gamma$ and $\delta+1$ are roots of the polynomial $x^3-x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$, and both $\delta$ and $\gamma+2$ are roots of the polynomial $x^3-x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$.

So letting $\phi(\gamma) = \delta+1$ [and $\phi(y)=y$ for each $y \in \mathbb{F}_3$], it follows that $\gamma$ and $\phi(\gamma)=\delta+1$ are both roots of the polynomial $x^3-x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$. This is necessary and sufficient for  Property 1 to hold, as $x^3-x^2+1$ is irreducible.

Thus the mapping ; $\phi(\gamma) = \delta+1$ is the desired isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Mike

Answer (score 1):

Both $x^3-x^2+1$ and $x^3-x^2+x+1$ are irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$ (since  neither has a root).  Thus both quotients are the field $\Bbb F_{27}=\{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2\mid \alpha,\beta,\gamma \in\Bbb F_3\}$.